# Select data from database by selecting the dropdownlist options in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to select data from database based on options from dropdownlist like when i Select the A, it select data from table A but when i select B it should select data from Table.

here is my dropdownlist code:

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Project / پروژه</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control m-b" name="account">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option>Tawanmandi</option>
                                        <option>option 3</option>
                                        <option>option 4</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
```

here is my SQL Query

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'mis_db' );


if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 

           if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            //Table A and B should switch when i select the Option A or B from dropdownlist
              {
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM //A or B table';
                $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) ;

                if (!$data) {
                    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
                } else {

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                        echo "<tr>
                            <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>                                        
                          </tr>";
                     }
                 }
            }
                    ?>
```

Sorry for my bad english : (

Comment: Well, how would you normally set a variable based on the result of another variable? You're talking about using query A or query B here.

Comment: you should use two queries in if else condition on the basis of value of $_POST['account']

Comment: @tadman i want to get table name to mysql query based on options i select  from dropdownlist

Comment: As Vinit says: `if` is the key to your solution.

Comment: @VinitSingh Can you show me with codes : )

Comment: i write code for that you can try that its work for you@Farhad paikan

Answer (score 0):

You could write different queries on the basis of options selected. like this -

```
$query = '';

if($_POST['account']=='A') {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM tableA';
} else if($_POST['account']=='B') {
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM tableB';
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: I already did it in comment. Farhad asked for sample code that's why i posted this code snipet. even though i am editing my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($_POST['account']) {
    case 'Option A':
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM TableA';
        break;
    case 'Option B':
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM TableB';
        break;
    default:
        exit('unexpected input');
        break;
}
```

You can define your query like this. Actual Values, queries and behaviour for other values than A or B have to be adjusted.

I think you should prefer `switch` over `if`, as you can extend it more easily by simply adding `cases`.

Answer (score 0):

You can meet the requirement by using the jquery.
HTML Code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getData(){
        var tableName = $( "#myselect" ).val();
        if(tableName!=''){
            $.ajax({
                url:'database.php',
                data:{tableName:tableName},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });

        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Project</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><select  id ="myselect" class="form-control m-b" name="account" onchange="getData();">
            <option></option>
            <option>table1</option>
            <option>relation</option>
            <option>question</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And Database.php code is

```
$tableName = $_GET['tableName'];// die;
if($tableName!='') {
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if($con) {
    $db = mysql_select_db('test');
    if($db) {
     $query = mysql_query("Select * from ".$tableName) or die(mysql_error());
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
     echo $row['id'];
    }
  }
}
```